# Django How to make a custom contact form? In my index

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have in my `index.html` a custom contact form, like the following:

```
        <!-- FORM -->
            <form role="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Tema">
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="25" cols="10" placeholder="  Texto de su mensaje..."></textarea>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">Enviar mensaje</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- END FORM -->
```

In the `urls.py` file I have the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
#import createview which is the generic view for forms + validation
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
#import the user creation form
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from cfdipanel import forms
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^suscripcion$', views.suscripcion),
    url(r'^escritorio$', views.report_list),
    url(r'^report/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.report_detailh, name='report_detailh'),
    url(r'^login$', auth_views.login, {'template_name':
         'cfdipanel/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'},
         name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^profile$', views.profile),
    url(r'^registro$', views.registro, name='registro'),
]
```

How can I make this same form work in my index? That just send me a javascript alert that was sent, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First select the method to use, usually is post, and where should be redirect something like this `<form method="post" action="">` that will be redirect to the same page, if you want an alert use a var in your context like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #save form
    context = {'alert':'alert'}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

and in your template:

```
<head>
    ....
    {% if alert %}
        <script type="text/javascript">alert('Form save')</script>
    {% endif %}
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my forms.py like that:

forms.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model=Contact
    fields = ['name','email','subject','message']

    widgets = {

        "name":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id':"name"}),
        "email":forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id':"email"}),
        "subject":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id':"subject"}),


        "message": forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id':"message", 'row':'3'})
    }
```

and in my html file:

```
<form method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="name">Your Name </label>
                    {{form.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="email">Your Email *</label>
                    {{form.email}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Your Subject</label>
                {{form.subject}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="message">Your message *</label>
                {{form.message}}
            </div>
```

but best way is [here](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-contact-form-for-website-in-Django.php)